# Trim Java ArrayList to distinct row with the newest date

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `List` of `MyData` as below. 
It consist of multiple rows of MyData objects.
There are some with same `key` but different `date` and `name`

```
public class MyData {
    String name;
    String key;
    String date;
    // ... constructor and other codes omitted here
}

List<MyData> myDataList;
```

I'm thinking of trimming the list to distinct `key` based on the newest `date`

e.g. If I have

```
*Name* *key* *date*
 ABC    12    2016-10-09
 FGH    10    2016-10-18
 IJK    10    2016-10-08
 DEF    12    2016-10-19
```

then the trim result should be

```
*Name* *key* *date*
 DEF    12    2016-10-19
 FGH    10    2016-10-18
```

What's the best way to do this algorithmically?

Note: I'm on Java 7, can't use the Stream feature of Java 8. (This is for Android Development, Java 8 is not supported yet).

Comment: Please let me know if this question has some issue before down voting it. I will improve it, or remove it if this is inappropriate. Thanks.

Comment: You could sort by key&date, then iterate and retain the last item of each "key group".

Comment: Are two `MyData` instances considered equal if they have the same key? (I.e. have you overwritten `equals` and `hashCode` to do so?)

Comment: Nope, I haven't override the equal or hashcode. But don't mind doing so if that could improve the performance. One thing though is, I want to retain the newest date data.

Comment: If you want to use Java Streams, this would be a duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040945/java-8-lambda-for-selecting-top-salary-employee-for-each-department

Comment: Nope, I can't use JavaStream, as I'm using Java 7 only. Mainly for Android Development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use real date types for `date` attribute you could do this:

```
private Collection<MyData> trim(List<MyData> data) {
    Map<String, MyData> result = new HashMap<>();
    for (MyData item : data) {
        MyData lastItem = result.get(item.getKey());
        if (lastItem == null || lastItem.getDate().before(item.getDate())) {
            result.put(item.getKey(), item);
        }
    }
    return result.values();
}
```

You could probably reach same results using streams.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Great indeed. I upvote it. Also I like the function itself doing the work. I'm ticking this as the answer. Thanks much!

Comment: If you think my question is appropriate, perhaps you could help upvote it. I don't think it deserved a -1. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Boris, can we cast the Collection back to List?

Comment: Found it, just `new ArrayList<MyData>(result.values);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **HashMap** and update object corresponding to key only if it is more recent. I let you write the function to compare two dates.

```
HashMap<Integer, MyData> trimedData = new HashMap<>();
for (MyData d : myDataList){
    MyData dataSaved= trimedData.get(d.key);
    if (dataSaved!= null){
        if(d.date > dataSaved.data){ // Here use correct method to compare date
            trimedData.put(d.key, d);
        }
    }
    else trimedData.put(d.key, key); 
}
```

Comment: If you think my question is appropriate, perhaps you could help upvote it. I don't think it deserved a -1. Thanks!

Comment: I think your question wasn't stupid and did not downvote it.

Comment: I know you didn't downvote it. Just thought if you could help upvote to neutralize it to 0, if you think that is appropriate. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams, look at this example:

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add("cbab");
strings.add("abab");
strings.add("dabab");
strings.add("ddabab");
Map<Integer, Optional<String>> collect = strings
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length,
        Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt((c) -> (int) charAt(0)))));
System.out.println(collect);
```

Change `String::length` to `MyData::key` and comparator to comparing dates (`Collectors.maxBy((MyData d1, Mydate d2) -> d1.getDate().compareTo(d2.getDate())`.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use stream.