# Java 8 Stream api for selecting top 3 employee name sorted by salary for each department

Tags: java, java-stream

I have map `Map<String, List<employee>> empMap` . key as department and value as a list of associated employees. I want to print the top 3 employees from each department who have the highest salary using java stream API.

Comment: what you have tried so far? Share the code and structure of Employee and Department

Comment: What happens when there's two or more employees which have the same salary and that salary is one of the three highest salaries?

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040945/java-8-lambda-for-selecting-top-salary-employee-for-each-department?

Answer (score 1):

```
empMap.stream().sorted(-> {/*sorting*/}).limit(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to use stream for map's value but not for original map itself. Using sorting as @Jochen suggested you could get 3 employees from top of sorted list:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Employee>> entry : empMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey());  // print department name

    entry.getValue().stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(Employee::getSalary).reversed())
            .limit(3)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```