# Java Stream - maxBy - How to find a department with the highest Average salary with Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I have a list of `Employee`.

```
public class Employee {
    private String department;
    private double salary;
    // other properties
}
```

I am trying to find the name of the department which has the highest average salary.

*The code I've tried:*

```
List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
employeeList.add(new Employee("abc", 38, "M", "QA", 115000.00d, 2016));
employeeList.add(new Employee("def", 23, "M", "Sports", 5000000.00d, 2011));
employeeList.add(new Employee("ghi", 38, "M", "QA", 120000.00d, 2007));
employeeList.add(new Employee("jkl", 35, "M", "DEV", 50000.00d, 2016));
employeeList.add(new Employee("mno", 30, "F", "QA", 80000.00d, 206));
employeeList.add(new Employee("pqr", 32, "F", "DEV", 75000.00d, 2014));

Map<String, Double> highestAvgSalary = employeeList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        emp -> emp.getDepartment(),
        Collectors.averagingDouble(emp -> emp.getSalary(),                        
            Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparingDouble(emp -> emp.getSalary()))
```

The last line of the code is triggering a compilation error. How do I have to apply `maxBy()` to get maximum avg salary of the department?

Comment: You want an average salary of each dept or  the department which have the highest avg salary ?

Comment: Department which has the highest avg salary

Comment: Your code is almost there `highestAvgSalary =employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(emp -> emp.getDepartment(), Collectors.averagingDouble(emp -> emp.getSalary());` .  Then you can use `String key = Collections.max(highestAvgSalary.entrySet(), Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).getKey();`

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36040945/java-8-lambda-for-selecting-top-salary-employee-for-each-department

Comment: @SayanBhattacharya Can you please explain the two arguments of Collections.max and any online reference to study?

Comment: @nikhiludgirkar You can follow this tutorial https://www.javatpoint.com/java-collections-max-method  .  After that you can search what is `map.entryset` & `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` I hope you will get your answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Collectors.averagingDouble()` expects only one argument - a *function* which turn stream element into `Double`. Attempt of passing a downstream collector is incorrect.

This task can't be fulfilled in a single iteration over the collection of *employees* as mentioned by *@Sayan Bhattacharya* in the comments.

We need to create a stream over the map entries of the intermediate `Map` that associates debarment-name with its average salary and apply [`max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)) operation on it.

```
Map.Entry<String, Double> highestAvgSalary = employeeList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Employee::getDepartment,
        Collectors.averagingDouble(Employee::getSalary)
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .get();
```

***Note*** that `max()` produces an `Optional`. And Optional API offers different ways to extract result from it. Method `get()` might produce a `NoSuchElementException`, in case of an empty optional. If you have a custom exception for that case - replace it with [`orElseThrow(Supplier)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow(java.util.function.Supplier)). Since Java 10 according to the documentation `get()` **isn't encouraged** to be used (unless you're not sure that result is present), the recommended practice is to use the parameterless flavor of `orElseThrow()`. Obviously, you can't use it with **Java 8**, only for that reason in the code above I've applied `get()` (with lower versions it's somewhat justifiable to avoid verbosity). But you still have other alternatives like `orElse()` and `orElseGet()`.

Also note that having `Map` as the resulting type would not be very handy since you don't know the name of the department with the highest salary in advance (*which would be the key of the only entry contained in the map*). Hence, you can't access the information with in such map in a convenient way. But if you really need a *single-entry-map* for some reason, then instead of `get()` in the code above, you can apply `map(Map::ofEntries).get()` and it would give you `Map<String, Double>` as a result.

Comment: Could you please explain here the return type: We are just returning the Double i.e. Map.Entry::getValue but it returns the key as well i.e. department Sports.

Comment: @nikhiludgirkar `groupingBy` produces a `Map<String,Double>` - *average department salary* by *name*. Then a stream over its entries is being created. Method `max()` expects a `Compactor` that would allow comparing *map-entries* (the type of elements in the second stream as well as the return type is of the stream pipe-line is `Map.Entry<String,Double>`).

Comment: @nikhiludgirkar The comparator we need can be written either as `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()` or `Comparator.comparingDouble(Map.Entry::getValue)`

Comment: @nikhiludgirkar If your question was about the syntax of the expression `Map.Entry::getValue`, then have a look https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html

Comment: @alexanderInvanchenko No not the syntax. I got your first comment. Thanks